# ¿Cómo solucionar java.lang.NullPointerException en Netbeans al usar imágenes? Java with Maven

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, macos

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Java Swing en el editor de interfaces gráficas de Netbeans y al utilizar imágenes dentro de etiquetas en el proyecto este no compila y me salta una excepción tipo java.lang.NullPointerException. Si elimino la imagen de la etiqueta no me genera ese error, pero no es el punto. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?
Netneans genera el código automáticamente, por lo que no puedo modificar las lineas que me marca como error. Tal vez el error sea algo de configuración. El principal problema radica en que si le indico el paquete en el que están las imágenes y la imagen en concreto que deseo, el programa no compila, pero si le doy de forma externa toda la ruta del proyecto sí; sin embargo al copiar el proyecto o moverlo de carpeta, las etiquetas se quedan vacías porque la dirección ya no coincide. Intenté colocarle la ruta relativa en lugar de la absoluta, pero en ese caso tampoco funciona. Repito: el código no lo puedo modificar porque Netbeans lo genera automáticamente. Uso el SO MacOS.
El código generado es el siguiente:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ventana;

/**
 *
 * @author pedrovazquezg
 */
public class Ventana extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Ventana
     */
    public Ventana() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        imagenC1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tituloC1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        generoC1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        imagenC2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tituloC2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        generoC2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        imagenC3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tituloC3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        generoC3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        imagenC4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tituloC4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        generoC4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Caricaturas");

        panel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        imagenC1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/Users/pedrovazquezg/OneDrive - Universidad de Guanajuato/Universidad/UG/04 Cursos/Udemy/Java/13 Interfaces gráficas de usuario/Ejercicio7/src/main/java/imagenes/spiderman.jpg")); // NOI18N
        imagenC1.setLabelFor(imagenC1);
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(20, 20, 0, 0);
        panel.add(imagenC1, gridBagConstraints);

        tituloC1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        tituloC1.setText("Título: The Spectacular Spider Man");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(20, 20, 0, 20);
        panel.add(tituloC1, gridBagConstraints);

        generoC1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 13)); // NOI18N
        generoC1.setText("Género: Acción");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(10, 20, 0, 20);
        panel.add(generoC1, gridBagConstraints);

        imagenC2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/Users/pedrovazquezg/OneDrive - Universidad de Guanajuato/Universidad/UG/04 Cursos/Udemy/Java/13 Interfaces gráficas de usuario/Ejercicio7/src/main/java/imagenes/adventuretime.jpg")); // NOI18N
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(20, 20, 0, 0);
        panel.add(imagenC2, gridBagConstraints);

        tituloC2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        tituloC2.setText("Título: Adventure Time");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(20, 20, 0, 20);
        panel.add(tituloC2, gridBagConstraints);

        generoC2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 13)); // NOI18N
        generoC2.setText("Género: Aventura");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(10, 20, 0, 20);
        panel.add(generoC2, gridBagConstraints);

        imagenC3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/Users/pedrovazquezg/OneDrive - Universidad de Guanajuato/Universidad/UG/04 Cursos/Udemy/Java/13 Interfaces gráficas de usuario/Ejercicio7/src/main/java/imagenes/simpsons.jpg")); // NOI18N
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(20, 20, 0, 0);
        panel.add(imagenC3, gridBagConstraints);

        tituloC3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        tituloC3.setText("Título: The Simpsons");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 4;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(20, 20, 0, 20);
        panel.add(tituloC3, gridBagConstraints);

        generoC3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 13)); // NOI18N
        generoC3.setText("Género: Comedia");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 5;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(10, 20, 0, 20);
        panel.add(generoC3, gridBagConstraints);

        imagenC4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/Users/pedrovazquezg/OneDrive - Universidad de Guanajuato/Universidad/UG/04 Cursos/Udemy/Java/13 Interfaces gráficas de usuario/Ejercicio7/src/main/java/imagenes/rickandmorty.jpg")); // NOI18N
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 6;
        gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(20, 20, 0, 0);
        panel.add(imagenC4, gridBagConstraints);

        tituloC4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        tituloC4.setText("Título: Rick and Morty");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 6;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(20, 20, 0, 20);
        panel.add(tituloC4, gridBagConstraints);

        generoC4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 13)); // NOI18N
        generoC4.setText("Género: Ciencia ficción");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 7;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(10, 20, 0, 20);
        panel.add(generoC4, gridBagConstraints);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(panel);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 480, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 640, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ventana.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ventana.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ventana.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Ventana.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Ventana().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel generoC1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel generoC2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel generoC3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel generoC4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel imagenC1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel imagenC2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel imagenC3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel imagenC4;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tituloC1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tituloC2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tituloC3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tituloC4;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

El mensaje de error es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at ventana.Ventana.initComponents(Ventana.java:40)
    at ventana.Ventana.<init>(Ventana.java:18)
    at ventana.Ventana$1.run(Ventana.java:96)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Hola. Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el código relevante a este error

Comment: Una disculpa, soy nuevo en esto. Ya incluí más detalles.

Comment: Has probado anteponiendo "src/" antes de ir al paquete donde has colocado las imágenes.

Comment: Estás en mac, gnu/linux o en windows? Cuando java intenta leer un archivo, `/` NO hace referencia a `C://` o a `/` (la raíz del filesystem) sino a la raíz del classpath y empieza a buscar por ahí, lo cual es correcto pues así haces tu código portable para que no solo funcione en tu computadora. Yo diría que, independientemente de si encuentras una solución o no, incluyas los archivos estáticos dentro del mismo jar, usualmente siempre se ponen el la carpeta `resources`

Comment: @BenjamínGuzmán Uso MacOS. Los archivos están dentro de un paquete del proyecto llamado imágenes. No sé si se deba al SO, pero en mi caso si no coloco la ruta absoluta, no funciona.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, no leí todo el código, perdón, vi la ruta absoluta y pensé que no estaba dentro del paquete. Como sea, te recomiendo que utilices una ruta relativa y leas el archivo con [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te agradecería si ordenaras un poco más el código muestras el error pero no que línea te da, ahora hay que recordar que un Null Pointer Exception se da cuando implementas algo que no has inicializado, en este caso agregaste el método pero su valor es nulo, debes inicializarlo dandole un valor.

Comment: @carloszamora Gracias por la bienvenida. Realmente el código no sirve de mucho… El error, como lo mencioné en la descripción, se encuentra en las lineas donde coloca las imágenes con la ruta absoluta. Se trata más que nada de un error de Netbeans en la configuración gráfica, de lo contrario podría colocar ruta relativa. No puedo modificar el código ya que este se genera automáticamente.

Comment: En tal caso, te recomiendo otro IDE como Eclipse, el cuál siento que es mucho mejor que NetBeans debido a la gran cantidad de errores que ha empezado a tener desde hace un tiempo. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema radica en el tipo de proyecto en el que se trabaja. Estaba utilizando Java Application with Maven que era el que generaba ese error (no tengo idea del motivo ya que debería de ser lo mismo, si alguien sabe el motivo espero que complemente esto), **utilizando Java Application with Ant (la versión clásica) no da ese error y se puede trabajar perfectamente con las imágenes en Netbeans sin ningún problema utilizando la ruta relativa**.